# get all Index on mongodb deployment

Tags: mongodb

Please help me with the mongodb query, which will return all the index in the mongodb deployment .
Also , this query will exclude the views and takes only the collection . please help on the same .

below command works, but fails on dealing with "views" .

```
test01_rs:PRIMARY>  db.adminCommand('listDatabases').databases.forEach(function(e){ if ((e.name == "admin" || e.name == "config" || e.name == "local")) return; var database=e.name; context=db.getSiblingDB(database); context.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collection){ records=context.getCollection(collection).aggregate( [ { $indexStats: { } }, { "$group" : { _id : { name: "$name"}, accesses:{$sum:"$accesses.ops"}, since:{$min:"$accesses.since"}, } }, { "$project": { _id:0, name:"$_id.name", since:{ $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S", date: "$since" } }, accesses:"$accesses", } } ] ).forEach(function(index){ idx=index.name; since=index.since; accesses=index.accesses; print(database+";"+collection+";"+idx+";"+since+";"+accesses); }); }); });
```

Test03;fahed;*id*;2022-01-10-17:31:26;0
Test04;fahed;*id*;2022-01-10-17:31:26;0
Test05;fahed;*id*;2022-01-10-17:31:26;0

thanks,
Fahed

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

```
db.adminCommand( { listDatabases: 1 } ).databases.forEach(
    function(d){
      print('databaseName:'+d.name);
      db.getSiblingDB(d.name).getCollectionInfos({type:"collection"}).forEach(
        function(collection){ indexes = 
          db.getSiblingDB(d.name).getCollection(collection.name).getIndexes();
          print("Indexes on "+d.name+"."+ collection.name + ":");
          printjson(indexes) 
         })
      })
```

this will provide you output like:

```
 databaseName:x
 Indexes on x.col1:
 [ { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: '_id_' } ]
 databaseName:y
 Indexes on y.col2:
 [ { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: '_id_' } ]
```

Explained:

1. Get array with list of database names with listDatabase:1 command.
2. Loop on the provided database list and getCOllectionInfos ( filtering only collections of type: collection to exclude views )
3. Loop on the list of provided collections and execute getIndexes() to list all indices as requested.

tested with mongosh 0.12.1 / mongod 4.4.12

**Option 2:**

```
    db.adminCommand( { listDatabases: 1 } ).databases.forEach(function(d){ print('databaseName:'+d.name);db.getSiblingDB(d.name).getCollectionInfos({type:"collection"}).forEach(function(collection){ indexes = db.getSiblingDB(d.name).getCollection(collection.name).aggregate([ {$indexStats:{}} ]); indexes.forEach(function(idx){   print("Indexes on "+d.name+"."+ collection.name + ": idx:"+idx.name+" ,since:"+idx.accesses.since+" accesses:"+idx.accesses.ops  ); } )    }) })
```

for this option you will need to add some additional privilges to your user ...

Here index details taken from $indexStats containing since access

Comment: thanks R2D2 for the answer , 

is it possible to get the output like array, like below ,

 print(database+";"+collection+";"+idx+";"+since+";"+accesses)

Comment: you can do by adding one more loop over the array of indices ...

Comment: added option 2 to my answer including indexStats options to fetch access since ...

Comment: thanks R2D2 , for helping me on this ., got one more query on this,
for option 2, which previlege we need to add on to user ?

Comment: You will need the indexStats privilege: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/privilege-actions/#indexStats